# Differentiation under an infinite sum for increasing function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, +\infty)$ be a sequence of increasing functions, and suppose that

$f(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} f_n(x) < \infty$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Prove that

$f'(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} f_n'(x)$ for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I was trying to prove two inequalities: $f'(x)\ge \sum_{n\ge 1} f'_n(x)$ is easy, but in order to prove the reversed one I got into several problems...

Comment: @user160940 Such as...

Comment: By definition, $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)}{h}$. My idea was to stop the sum at $\sum_{n=1}^{N}$, get an estimate on the tail using positivity and/or the increasing property (this estimate kind of independent of $h$ - in some way) and then taking $h$ small to make the first sum littler than $\sum_{n=1}^N f_n'(x) +\epsilon$.

Comment: But this leads to an infinite cycle: if I estimate the tail so that it gets 'small' ($<|h|\epsilon$, for example), then I have to make $N$ bigger, which leads me to another estimate on the tail and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help from a friend, this one was solved:

For the reversed inequality, let

$$ f(x) = S_n(x) + r_n(x)$$,

Where $S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k (x)$ and $r_n(x) = \sum_{k > n} f_k(x)$. Then we've that

$$ f'(x) = S_n'(x) + r_n'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k'(x) + r_n'(x)$$

Now we claim that, for every $[a,b]$ bounded interval, we have that $ r_n' \rightarrow 0 $ in $L^1([a,b])$. Indeed,

$$ \int_a^b r_n'(t) dt \le \sum_{k>n} \int_a^b f_k'(t) dt \le \sum_{k>n} [f_k(b)-f_k(a)]  $$

And the last sum clearly goes to zero with $n$. Here we have used, in the first inequality, $f' \ge \sum_k f_k'$ and Fubini's Theorem. Thus, for almost every $x \in [a,b]$ we will have that there exist a subsequence $r_{n_k}' (x)\rightarrow 0$. But as $r_n' = r_{n_k}'-f_{n_k}' - \cdots - f_{n -1}' $, where the last terms are all nonpositive, we conclude that for these $x$ we also have that $r_n'(x) \rightarrow 0$.

From this, we conclude that, for almost every $x \in [a,b]$,

$$f'(x) \le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k'(x) + r_n'(x) \rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k'(x)$$

And this proves the claim for these $x$.

To finish, pick the intervals as $[a,b] = [-N,N]$, and as the intersection of countably many full-measure sets is still a full-measure set, we finish the proof.

Comment: Why the last summation goes to zero?

Comment: It seems you are using $f' \leq \sum_k f_k'$ and not $f' \geq \sum_k f_k'$. Proving $f' \leq \sum_k f_k'$ does not seem obvious. Please clarify if possible.