# Showing $F'(x)=\sum_n F_n'(x)$ a.e. $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $F_n$ be non-negative increasing right continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$ with the property that

$$\sup_n F_n(1)<\infty.$$

If $F(x)=\sum_n F_n(x)$ and $F(1)<\infty$ prove

$$F'(x)=\sum_n F_n'(x)$$

for a.e. $x$.

So my first thoughts were to use something like MCT as the $F_n$ are increasing and non-negative, but I fail to see where to use the assumptions $\sup_n F_n(1)<\infty$ and $F(1)<\infty$. any hints or tips greatly appreciated. I know right continuous functions are measurable so I can invoke a convergence theorem with no issue.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4731732/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/859612/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/937322/42969.

Comment: @MartinR these don’t have any solutions , the last one specially. Am I on the right track with invoking MCT?

Comment: The first two have answers, don't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct solution distinct from the answers referenced above.

Since the series has nonnegative terms, it has a limit at each point and since the functions are increasing, the limit is increasing too, so $F(1) < \infty$ means the series converges everywhere.

Then it is clear that for all $h \ne 0$ we have $(F(x+h)-F(x))/h \ge \sum_{n \le N} (F(x_n+h)-F(x_n))/h$ since all the ratios are nonnegative, hence taking $h \to 0$ at the ae differentiable points of all of $F, F_n$ we get $F'(x) \ge \sum F_n'(x)=G(x)$ ae. So we need to prove that $F'>G$ has measure zero and we do this by a standard measure-theoretic trick:

Let also $S_N(x)=\sum_{n \le N}F_n(x), S_N'=G_N \le G$

If $E(p,q)$ is the set of points where $G(x)< p <q<F'(x)$ for some rational $p,q$ (here assuming implicitly that all derivatives exist at such $x$) and there is a set $E=E(p,q)$ of positive measure $\alpha>0$ we have $G_N<p<q<F'$ on $E$ so if we pick $x \in E$ we can find $h=h_{N,x}>0$ small enough st $$S_N(x+h)-S_N(x)<ph<qh<F(x+h)-F(x)$$ as $(S_N(x+h)-S_N(x))/h \to G_N$ etc.

By usual arguments (considering the set of disjoint intervals with the property above, ordering them by inclusion and applying a maximality argument) we can ensure that we cover any fixed fraction of $E$ so in particular at least $\alpha/2$ with such.

Since on each we have $$(F(x+h)-S_N(x+h))-(F(x)-S_N(x)) \ge h(q-p)$$ using that $F-S_N$ is increasing and summing we get $$(q-p)\alpha/2 \le (F(1)-S_N(1))-(F(0)-S_N(0))$$ for arbitrary fixed $N$ which contradicts $\alpha>0$ as $N \to \infty$

(in the above we use that for any partition $0 \le x_1<y_1<x_2<y_2<...x_m<y_m \le 1$ and $H$ increasing we have

$H(y_m)-H(x_m))+...(H(y_1)-H(x_1))=$

$=H(y_m)-(H(x_m)-H(y_{m-1})-..-(H(x_2)-H(y_1))-H(x_1)$

$\le H(1)-H(0)$

since all the brackets are nonnegative and a limit argument for infinite partitions as above)

Hence all $E(p,q)$ have measure zero and since the set where $G<F'$ is the union of such (on all rational pairs $p<q$), it has measure zero and we are done!